# Firing event in renderer issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, event, security-review

I am using highcharts in my lightning components which is embedded in a lightning app. When clicking on the chart , I am firing an event. the method to draw the chart is called from renderer. And the security review says "**You should not fire an event in a renderer**" eventhough the event is fired only when it is clicked. 
The code snippet is shown below.

```
  events: {
    click: function () {
       var dataValue = this.y;
       var categoryName = this.series.name;

       var updateEvent = component.getEvent("updateExpense");
       updateEvent.setParams({ 
          "dataValue": dataValue,
          "categoryName"" categoryName
       });
       updateEvent.fire();
    }
  }
```

What should I do here, because its an inevitable functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you draw your chart from Helper.js?

Comment: Actually I am drawing the chart in helper.js but the particular method is called from renderer.